# Rails: any way to refactor this ActiveRecord code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, refactoring

I have a piece of code that checks that a survey response picked by user to a survey question is in fact one of valid choices:

```
Question.find_by_id(question_id).question_choices.all(:select => 'id').map {|x| x.id}.include?(user_choice_id)
```

Is there an easier way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least the `question_choices.all(:select => 'id').map {|x| x.id}` component can be rewritten, as ActiveRecord provides a method for this `question_choice_ids`.

You can also just do `find` instead of `find_by_id`. I know that `find` will raise an exception if nothing is found, but so will calling `question_choices` on `nil` in your example, anyway:

```
Question.find(question_id).question_choice_ids.include?(user_choice_id)

# or 

# Rails 2 (will run 2 queries unless you use :include)
Question.find(question_id).question_choices.first(:conditions => {:id => user_choice_id})

# Rails 3 (will only run 1 query)
Question.find(question_id).question_choices.where(:id => user_choice_id).first
```

Comment: Thank you for your insightful reply. You understand my problem correctly. However I don't think that the last two code fragments(using conditions and named_scope) will work. Since the only parameter entered is the choice_id. This would find the question for which this choice is valid, but not check whether a give choice is valid for given question.

Comment: Missing extra conditions constrain: :conditions => { {:id => question_id}, {:question_choices => {:id => answer} }

Comment: Ah you are right, it would need the `question_id` too. I didn't write a test application to test them, but at least you got the gist. I am updating my examples with another way to do it that's nicer